# gcc error installing python cryptography centos 7 64

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos7

I have a Centos 7 64bit updated.
I'm trying to install python cryptography using this command:

```
 pip install cryptography
```

But I got this error message:

```
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: cryptography
Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lulu_cn7/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2t0eqhin-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.c:12:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <pyconfig.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lulu_cn7/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2t0eqhin-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lulu_cn7/cryptography/
```

I look everywhere for a solution but no luck
Here version of my packages:

Python 2.7.5
Python 3.4.5
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `yum install -y python34-devel`, as you lack the libraries it provides. If you don't have the package, you probably don't have EPEL in your repositories. Add it with `yum install epel-release`.

Comment: yes already done. Package python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: I have edited my answer, as I have noticed that you use python3, not python2 (you have python-devel for python2).

Comment: thanks, I already tried this, but centos7 doesn't have the that package:yum install -y python3-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.fastbull.org
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: centos.fastbull.org
 * updates: centos.fastbull.org
No package python3-devel available

Comment: I installed python34-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.5-3.el7 from EPL repository and it works!